# GatsbyJS/WordPress add support logo GraphQL

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, wp-graphql

I'm trying to add custom logo to my GatsbyJS site but having issues to query the logo in GraphQL. The site is build with gatsby-source-graphql & WPGraphQL WordPress plugin. I've added theme support in my WordPress functions.php with below code:

```
function tt_custom_logo_setup() {
 $defaults = array(
      'show_in_graphql' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'graphql_single_name' => 'Logo',
      'graphql_plural_name' => 'Logoer',
 );
 add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', $defaults );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'tt_custom_logo_setup' );
```

After uploading logo I ran gatsby clean and then gatsby develop but the logo doesn't seem to show in GraphQL. What am I missing??